# If index is out of bounds of array, set index to closest boundary

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, math

Let's say we have an array that can have a length of 1 to ??

We have a way of navigating this array up or down by clicking a button that either navigates upward or downward, which is displayed in the DOM (think pagination).

We would want our navigation to stop when either we are out of the lower bound, or stop when our navigation is out of the upper bound.

When we reach the lower-bound we would know this by the value **-1**

When we reach the upper-bound we would know this by the value **( > array.length - 1 )**.

Our function accepts the parameter index as shown

```
function goToChapter( index ){
  // compute value of index to within bounds.
  return array[ index ];
}
```

Let's say all we want to do is use the computed within bounds index to get a value from the returned array.

> Examples

```
var array ["chapZero", "chapOne", "chapTwo", "chapThree"];

goToChapter( 2 );
=> "chapTwo;

goToChapter( 4 );
=> "chapThree"; // because four is out of upper bound so index became three.

goToChapter( -1 );
=> "chapZero"; // because -1 is our of lower bound so index became zero.
```

I realize this can be done with a few if statements, I am looking for a way to use some sort of math formula that perhaps

1. converts any negative number to 0;
2. leaves any positive number alone;
3. uses the length of the array to determine when to return the upper limit.

**UPDATE**

I'm going with Andand's answer. I've added enough to copy paste the solution into the console if you find this helpful and want to test it out.

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4];

function goToChapter( index, array ){
  return array[(Math.min( array.length - 1, Math.max( 0, index )))];
}

goToChapter( -1, array ); => 0;

goToChapter( 3, array ); => 3;

goToChapter( 8, array ); => 4;
```

Thanks Andand.

**NOTE:**

I also found this helpful, but not as fast.

```
function setWithinArrayBounds( index, array ){
  return !!index ? 0 : index > ( array.length - 1 ) ? ( array.length - 1 ) : index;
}
```

Comment: For things like this I always define a static `clapm(min, max, value)` function in some utility class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is known as clamping a value to restrict it to a specified range.

You could use `min()` and `max()` as in something like:

```
function goToChapter(array, index ){
    myIndex = Math.min(array.length-1, Math.max(0, index));
    return array[ myIndex ];
}
```

Another way is with nested ternary operators such as

```
function goToChapter(array, index ){
    myIndex = index < 0 
        ? 0
        : index >= array.length
            ? array.length - 1
            : index;
    return array[ myIndex ];
}
```

You could also use an `if` statement as in

```
function goToChapter(array, index ){
    if (index < 0) {
        myIndex = 0;
    } else if (index >= array.length) {
        myIndex = array.length-1;
    } else {
        myIndex = index;
    }

    return array[ myIndex ];
}
```

Or a variation using sequential `if` statements on this could be

```
function goToChapter(array, index ){
    myIndex = index;

    if (myIndex < 0) {
        myIndex = 0;
    }

    if (myIndex >= array.length) {
        myIndex = array.length-1;
    }

    return array[ myIndex ];
}
```

Comment: I like this, can you change myArray to just array, and include Math. in your min and max, as well as include an actual array and the returned value. That way someone can just copy paste your answer into the console and test it out; and I'll accept your answer.